# convert blank space from char to wchar_t

Tags: c++, mfc

Say I wanna textout lines of texts in MFC, formating the texts to be right-aligned like:

```
1234

 225

  64
```

But the following code does not work well:

```
 wchar_t test[20];
 int i;
 swprintf(test, L"%4d",i);
```

It seems the blank space converted in wchar_t still occupies only a byte of space, not two, and thus the texts are not aligned. Is there a simple way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized... What exactly is this example supposed to print?

Comment: what has `mfc` to do with this? If you're trying to display on a text box or other widget, the widget will have a right alignment property for text no?

Comment: Read something about value justification.

Comment: It is actually an interesting observation provided it is true. Both the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25366k66(v=vs.120).aspx) and [linux](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) documentation say that the width field _controls the minimum number of characters that are output_. The OP observes that it is in fact the number of bytes, not characters. I have not tested it myself, but if in fact it is a bug there is a workaround I have in mind

Comment: @EdChum: The OP is looking for a way align text at the right edge, still displaying it relative to the left edge. This is rarely supported in controls. Those usually only allow you to right-justify (also sometimes called "flush to right"), moving the text all the way to the far right edge. This is a solution to a different problem.

Comment: I use vs2013. The actual problem is the output size of different characters are different in GUI, unlike the console enviroment. E.g. dc.textoutw(1,1,L"llll"); dc.textoutw(1,61,"6666"); To be aligned, do I have to specify the position of each character?

Comment: Choosing a suitble font can fix it..

Comment: If you want each character in a string aligned in a GUI, either choose a monospace font, or call [ExtTextOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713.aspx) with a non-NULL *lpDx* argument. This array allows you to explicitly set the character origin offset between adjacent characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all other UTF-16 encoded characters, a space character consists of two-byte code units as well. The [swprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) call works as advertised<sup>1)</sup><sup>2)</sup>. The error is in the code or logic verifying your assumption, code we cannot see.

For reference, the following code

```
wchar_t test[20];
swprintf( test, L"%4d", 64 );
```

fills the buffer with the following sequence of bytes (character representations provided for reference):

```
0x20 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x36 0x00 0x34 0x00 0x00 0x00
+-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+
  L' '      L' '      L'6'      L'4'      L'\0'
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Verified using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.*
<sup>2)</sup> *Although you really should be using the ISO compliant [std::swprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf), taking an explicit destination buffer size argument.*